# scanf does not work with &str when str is defined as char str[100]

Tags: c, scanf

Please, can someone tell me what is the problem in my syntax. I want to find the duplicate letters in a word. it is working properly if I declare a character array here itself but not working with scanf.

```
#include<stdio.h>

// Finding the duplicate alphabets in a string

int length(char str[]) //Finding the length of the string
{
    int len;
    while(str[len]!='\0')
    {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
void duplicate(char str[],int n)
{
    int i,j,flag;
    for(i=0;i<=n-2;i++) //Selecting the alphabet for comparison
    {
        flag=0;
        if(str[i]!='\0')
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<=n-1;j++) //comparison of alphabets
            {
                if(str[j]==str[i])
                {
                    flag=1;
                    str[j]=0;
                }
            }
            if(flag==1)
            {
                printf("%c is the duplicate character\n",str[i]);
            }   
            
        }        
        
    } 
}
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    scanf("%s",&str);
    int n= length(str);
    duplicate(str,n);
}
```

Comment: Please choose a title that actually describes your problem. THank you.

Comment: Do you remember reading in your text-books that local variables are by default *uninitialized*?

Comment: Also, the `scanf` format `%s` expect an argument of type `char *`. while you give an argument of type `char (*)[100]`.

Comment: Does this fix your problem? ```scanf("%s",*&str);```

Comment: @MFerguson `scanf(" %99s", str);` would be preferable

Comment: `while(str[len]!='\0')` - what do you believe the value of `len` is on entry into that `while` loop ?

Comment: Correct type for returning lengths would be `size_t` – it is guaranteed to be large enough to cover *any* string allocatable on your system, and it's unsigned as well (negative lengths are meaningless anyway, aren't they?).

Comment: Off-topic: As you modify the string anyway: Your algorithm is an O(n²) one. You can improve it by *sorting* the string first – can be done in O(n*log(n)) – and then just iterate over linearly... There's [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort), if you are allowed to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems that I noticed:

1. main: `scanf("%s",&str);` is the wrong type for `str` (`char (*)[100]`) and should be `scanf("%s", str);`.   `char str[100]` uses a magic 100 value, instead `#define STR_LEN 99` so you can do `char str[STR_LEN + 1]`. The way you use `scanf` is subject to buffer overflow instead you should use `scanf("%" str(STR_LEN) "s", STR_LEN, str)` and you need `#define str(s) xstr(s)` and `#define xstr(s) #s`.  I suggest using `fgets` instead.
2. length: `int len;` is uninitialized and should be `int len = 0;`  (`len` is not a great variable name as it's usually 1 bigger than last index, but you use it to index with).  Why did you write your own instead of using `strlen`?  As you only return values 0 or great, consider using `unsigned` instead of `int` for the type of `i` and the return value.
3. duplicate (minor issue): it's good practice to minimize variable scope so `for(int i = 0; ...` and declare flags where you initilize it.  You should technically ensure that n > INT_MIN + 1 for underflow, or change type to an `unsigned` value, or just calculate it yourself internally.

You can also create an array of counts for each letter.  Initialized to 0, and add 1 as you find each letter.  Then report the letters with count > 1.  This would be a O(n) algorithm instead of the original O(n^2).

```
#include <limits.h>

#define CHARS (UCHAR_MAX+1)

void duplicate(char *str) {
    unsigned char counts[CHARS] = { 0 }; // 0, 1 or 2 for 2+
    for(unsigned i=0; str[i]; i++) {
        char *c = counts + (unsigned) str[i];
        *c += *c <= 1;
    }
    for(unsigned i=0; i<CHARS; i++) {
        if(counts[i] > 1) {
            printf("%c is the duplicate character\n", (char) i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reason why setting to 0: `"ababa"` would find `a` multiple times...

Comment: @Aconcagua  2 vs 3 instances of duplicates of 'a'.  Not sure either is correct but only op can tell us.

Comment: Well, the original version would have set both of the two following `a`s to 0 and only afterwards outputted (`flag`!) – so it would have printed just one single occurrence...

Comment: @Aconcagua you're right, I missed that while testing different ideas out.

Comment: Suggestion:  `++counts[ (unsigned char) str[i] ];`

Comment: @TedLyngmo done but ensuring counts don't overflow is preferable.

Comment: @Aconcagua could you clarify please?  If I am wrong then I learn something which is always welcome.

Comment: @AllanWind Make `counts` large enough, like `unsigned counts[CHARS];` and you can skip the complication when adding to the counts. I suggest also adding parentheses to the macro: `#define CHARS (UCHAR_MAX+1)`

Comment: `UCHAR_MAX` instead of `INT_MAX` looks nicer, and you need to increment `counts[...]` instead of `str[i]` – though I personally would go with `unsigned char* c = counts + (unsigned) str[i]; *c += *c <= 1;` – or for winning obfuscation competition `*c = *c << 1 | 1` ;)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Added the () but leaving it as is to protect against overflow (unsigned overflows, too).  The other good option is to cap at 2 as we only need 3 states (0, 1 and 2).

Comment: "*`scanf` is not safe to use*" is an overstatement, at best.  `scanf` can be used safely, though the OP's particular use is unsafe (open to buffer overflow).  `scanf` is also difficult to use correctly or appropriately in many circumstances, but that's not the same thing as "not safe".

Comment: @JohnBollinger I could remember wrong but I believe the gist is that some platforms don't null terminate the read string when reaching maximum field width.  It's also tricky that you need to pass an array of maximum field width + 1.

Comment: @AllanWind If you make the `counts[]` type into `uint32_t` instead of `unsigned char` I think you'd be safe against overflows. If that's not enough, `uint64_t` _should_ be safe for at least a couple of years. :-)

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks.  Updated the count as you suggested.

Comment: Apparently you remember wrongly, @AllanWind.  Although it is possible (and common) to use `scanf` unsafely, the function is not *inherently* unsafe.  For example, one can fail to specify a maximum field width in one's `%s` format, or specify an incorrect one, which opens the possibility of buffer overrun, but that's not "`scanf` is unsafe", it's "`scanf` is difficult to use correctly".

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for clarifying.  I will tweak my response accordingly.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Why discuss about `uintXX_t`? If we want to be safe in *any* case then we are with `size_t`...

Comment: @Aconcagua It seemed Allan wanted to keep the byte count down (why else use `unsigned char` to do counting) so with `uint32_t` and the max value of 4294967295 I thought it would be reasonably safe without taking up too much space.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Reasonable argument – so `uint32_t` if assuming maximum of suffices, `size_t` otherwise ;)

Comment: In support of @TedLyngmo's point, I looked it up earlier and apparently The Bible (as an example of a large corpus) has 3.5M letters (probably doesn't count spaces; and count of most frequent letter would be smaller than that) < UINT_MAX.  I initially used `int counts[]` but thought it was obnoxious to introduce an overflow condition (however unlikely) when I had pointed out that scanf is subject to a buffer overflow in the original code.

Comment: @AllanWind Just to make sure, you _could_ check for overflow when using `uint32_t` too. I'd go for something old-school like `if(counts[ (unsigned char) str[i] ] != UINT32_MAX) ++counts[ (unsigned char) str[i] ];`

Answer (score 0):

As advised, always ensure that your local variables are initialized before attempting to use them. As for your problem, if your sole desire is to find duplicate strings then you could approach it this way:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define CHAR_SIZE 100
int length(char[]);
void duplicate(char[], int);

// Finding the duplicate alphabets in a string
int length(char str[]) //Finding the length of the string
{
    int len = 0;
    while(str[len] !='\0')
        len++;
    return len;
}

//find duplicates
void duplicate(char str[],int n)
{
    for(int i =0; i < n; i++)
        for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
            if(str[i] == str[j])
                printf("%c is the duplicate character\n",str[i]);
}

//test case
int main()
{
    char str[CHAR_SIZE];
    puts("Enter string\n");
    scanf("%s",str);
    int n= length(str);
    printf("len of entered str is %d\n\n", n);
    duplicate(str,n);
}
```

Comment: Consider `"ababa"` – how many times would your version find `a` – compared to original version?